# How to decode ProposalResponsePayload in fabric-sdk-node

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I understand that sending a transaction proposal (like the code below)

```
    return channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);
}).then((proposalResponse) => {
//need to decode results
});
```

in which proposalResponse is a `ProposalResponseObject` (https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/global.html#ProposalResponseObject__anchor) in which ProposalResponseObject[0] is an array of `ProposalResponse`.

I too understand that 
`proposalResponse[0][i].response.payload` is the return message of `shim.Success`

But how to I decode `proposalResponse[0][i].payload` and `proposalResponse[1]`?

I tried to take a look at **BlockDecoder** (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.1/fabric-client/lib/BlockDecoder.js) but I can't find the correct method to decode the aforementioned items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into protobuf structure of the payload response and used codes in the BlockDecoder.js. In case anybody is interested:

```js
var grpc = require('grpc');
var _responseProto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/protos/peer/proposal_response.proto').protos;
var _proposalProto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/protos/peer/proposal.proto').protos;
var _rwsetProto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/protos/ledger/rwset/rwset.proto').rwset;
var _kv_rwsetProto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/protos/ledger/rwset/kvrwset/kv_rwset.proto').kvrwset;
var _ccEventProto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/protos/peer/chaincode_event.proto').protos;

module.exports = function decodeProposalResponsePayload(proposal_response_payload_bytes) {
 var proposal_response_payload = {};
 var proto_proposal_response_payload = _responseProto.ProposalResponsePayload.decode(proposal_response_payload_bytes);
 proposal_response_payload.proposal_hash = proto_proposal_response_payload.getProposalHash().toBuffer().toString('hex');
 proposal_response_payload.extension = decodeChaincodeAction(proto_proposal_response_payload.getExtension());

 return proposal_response_payload;
}

function decodeChaincodeAction(action_bytes) {
 var chaincode_action = {};
 var proto_chaincode_action = _proposalProto.ChaincodeAction.decode(action_bytes);
 chaincode_action.results = decodeReadWriteSets(proto_chaincode_action.getResults());
 chaincode_action.events = decodeChaincodeEvents(proto_chaincode_action.getEvents());
 chaincode_action.response = decodeResponse(proto_chaincode_action.getResponse());
 chaincode_action.chaincode_id = decodeChaincodeID(proto_chaincode_action.getChaincodeId());

 return chaincode_action;
}

function decodeReadWriteSets(rw_sets_bytes) {
 var proto_tx_read_write_set = _rwsetProto.TxReadWriteSet.decode(rw_sets_bytes);
 var tx_read_write_set = {};
 tx_read_write_set.data_model = proto_tx_read_write_set.getDataModel();
 if (proto_tx_read_write_set.getDataModel() === _rwsetProto.TxReadWriteSet.DataModel.KV) {
  tx_read_write_set.ns_rwset = [];
  let proto_ns_rwset = proto_tx_read_write_set.getNsRwset();
  for (let i in proto_ns_rwset) {
   let kv_rw_set = {};
   let proto_kv_rw_set = proto_ns_rwset[i];
   kv_rw_set.namespace = proto_kv_rw_set.getNamespace();
   kv_rw_set.rwset = decodeKVRWSet(proto_kv_rw_set.getRwset());
   tx_read_write_set.ns_rwset.push(kv_rw_set);
  }
 } else {
  // not able to decode this type of rw set, return the array of byte[]
  tx_read_write_set.ns_rwset = proto_tx_read_write_set.getNsRwset();
 }

 return tx_read_write_set;
}

function decodeKVRWSet(kv_bytes) {
 var proto_kv_rw_set = _kv_rwsetProto.KVRWSet.decode(kv_bytes);
 var kv_rw_set = {};

 // KV readwrite set has three arrays
 kv_rw_set.reads = [];
 kv_rw_set.range_queries_info = [];
 kv_rw_set.writes = [];

 // build reads
 let reads = kv_rw_set.reads;
 var proto_reads = proto_kv_rw_set.getReads();
 for (let i in proto_reads) {
  reads.push(decodeKVRead(proto_reads[i]));
 }

 // build range_queries_info
 let range_queries_info = kv_rw_set.range_queries_info;
 var proto_range_queries_info = proto_kv_rw_set.getRangeQueriesInfo();
 for (let i in proto_range_queries_info) {
  range_queries_info.push(decodeRangeQueryInfo(proto_range_queries_info[i]));
 }

 // build writes
 let writes = kv_rw_set.writes;
 var proto_writes = proto_kv_rw_set.getWrites();
 for (let i in proto_writes) {
  writes.push(decodeKVWrite(proto_writes[i]));
 }

 return kv_rw_set;
}

function decodeKVRead(proto_kv_read) {
 let kv_read = {};
 kv_read.key = proto_kv_read.getKey();
 let proto_version = proto_kv_read.getVersion();
 if (proto_version) {
  kv_read.version = {};
  kv_read.version.block_num = proto_version.getBlockNum().toString();
  kv_read.version.tx_num = proto_version.getTxNum().toString();
 } else {
  kv_read.version = null;
 }

 return kv_read;
}

function decodeRangeQueryInfo(proto_range_query_info) {
 let range_query_info = {};
 range_query_info.start_key = proto_range_query_info.getStartKey();
 range_query_info.end_key = proto_range_query_info.getEndKey();
 range_query_info.itr_exhausted = proto_range_query_info.getItrExhausted();

 // reads_info is one of QueryReads
 let proto_raw_reads = proto_range_query_info.getRawReads();
 if (proto_raw_reads) {
  range_query_info.raw_reads = {};
  range_query_info.raw_reads.kv_reads = [];
  for (let i in proto_raw_reads.kv_reads) {
   let kv_read = decodeKVRead(proto_raw_reads.kv_reads[i]);
   range_query_info.raw_reads.kv_reads.push(kv_read);
  }
 }
 // or QueryReadsMerkleSummary
 let proto_reads_merkle_hashes = proto_range_query_info.getReadsMerkleHashes();
 if (proto_reads_merkle_hashes) {
  range_query_info.reads_merkle_hashes = {};
  range_query_info.reads_merkle_hashes.max_degree = proto_reads_merkle_hashes.getMaxDegree();
  range_query_info.reads_merkle_hashes.max_level = proto_reads_merkle_hashes.getMaxLevel();
  range_query_info.reads_merkle_hashes.max_level_hashes = proto_reads_merkle_hashes.getMaxLevelHashes();
 }

 return range_query_info;
}

function decodeKVWrite(proto_kv_write) {
 let kv_write = {};
 kv_write.key = proto_kv_write.getKey();
 kv_write.is_delete = proto_kv_write.getIsDelete();
 kv_write.value = proto_kv_write.getValue().toBuffer().toString();

 return kv_write;
}

function decodeChaincodeEvents(event_bytes) {
 var events = {};
 var proto_events = _ccEventProto.ChaincodeEvent.decode(event_bytes);
 events.chaincode_id = proto_events.getChaincodeId();
 events.tx_id = proto_events.getTxId();
 events.event_name = proto_events.getEventName();
 events.payload = proto_events.getPayload().toBuffer();

 return events;
}

function decodeResponse(proto_response) {
 if (!proto_response) return null;
 var response = {};
 response.status = proto_response.getStatus();
 response.message = proto_response.getMessage();
 response.payload = proto_response.getPayload().toBuffer().toString();

 return response;
}

function decodeChaincodeID(proto_chaincode_id) {
 var chaincode_id = {};
 if(!proto_chaincode_id) {
  console.log('decodeChaincodeID - no proto_chaincode_id found');
  return chaincode_id;
 }
 chaincode_id.path = proto_chaincode_id.getPath();
 chaincode_id.name = proto_chaincode_id.getName();
 chaincode_id.version = proto_chaincode_id.getVersion();

 return chaincode_id;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for correctness. Still think it's absolutely mental that you have to do all this to read a response though..

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ProposalResponse Payload can be got from the TransactionActionInfo class and returns a byte[] array that can be decoded with a utility method .

```
 void blockWalker(Channel channel) throws InvalidArgumentException, ProposalException, IOException {
        try {
            BlockchainInfo channelInfo = channel.queryBlockchainInfo();

            for (long current = channelInfo.getHeight() - 1; current > -1; --current) {
                BlockInfo returnedBlock = channel.queryBlockByNumber(current);
                final long blockNumber = returnedBlock.getBlockNumber();

                out("current block number %d has data hash: %s", blockNumber, Hex.encodeHexString(returnedBlock.getDataHash()));
                out("current block number %d has previous hash id: %s", blockNumber, Hex.encodeHexString(returnedBlock.getPreviousHash()));
                out("current block number %d has calculated block hash is %s", blockNumber, Hex.encodeHexString(SDKUtils.calculateBlockHash(blockNumber, returnedBlock.getPreviousHash(), returnedBlock.getDataHash())));

                final int envelopCount = returnedBlock.getEnvelopCount();
                assertEquals(1, envelopCount);
                out("current block number %d has %d envelope count:", blockNumber, returnedBlock.getEnvelopCount());
                int i = 0;
                for (BlockInfo.EnvelopeInfo envelopeInfo : returnedBlock.getEnvelopeInfos()) {
                    ++i;

                    out("  Transaction number %d has transaction id: %s", i, envelopeInfo.getTransactionID());
                    final String channelId = envelopeInfo.getChannelId();


                    out("  Transaction number %d has channel id: %s", i, channelId);
                    out("  Transaction number %d has epoch: %d", i, envelopeInfo.getEpoch());
                    out("  Transaction number %d has transaction timestamp: %tB %<te,  %<tY  %<tT %<Tp", i, envelopeInfo.getTimestamp());
                    out("  Transaction number %d has type id: %s", i, "" + envelopeInfo.getType());

                    if (envelopeInfo.getType() == TRANSACTION_ENVELOPE) {
                        BlockInfo.TransactionEnvelopeInfo transactionEnvelopeInfo = (BlockInfo.TransactionEnvelopeInfo) envelopeInfo;

                        out("  Transaction number %d has %d actions", i, transactionEnvelopeInfo.getTransactionActionInfoCount());
                        out("  Transaction number %d isValid %b", i, transactionEnvelopeInfo.isValid());
                        out("  Transaction number %d validation code %d", i, transactionEnvelopeInfo.getValidationCode());

                        int j = 0;
                        for (BlockInfo.TransactionEnvelopeInfo.TransactionActionInfo transactionActionInfo : transactionEnvelopeInfo.getTransactionActionInfos()) {
                            ++j;
                            out("   Transaction action %d has response status %d", j, transactionActionInfo.getResponseStatus());
                            out("   Transaction action %d has response message bytes as string: %s", j,
                                    printableString(new String(transactionActionInfo.getResponseMessageBytes(), "UTF-8")));
                            out("   Transaction action %d has %d endorsements", j, transactionActionInfo.getEndorsementsCount());


                            for (int n = 0; n < transactionActionInfo.getEndorsementsCount(); ++n) {
                                BlockInfo.EndorserInfo endorserInfo = transactionActionInfo.getEndorsementInfo(n);
                                out("Endorser %d signature: %s", n, Hex.encodeHexString(endorserInfo.getSignature()));
                                out("Endorser %d endorser: %s", n, new String(endorserInfo.getEndorser(), "UTF-8"));
                            }
                            out("   Transaction action %d has %d chaincode input arguments", j, transactionActionInfo.getChaincodeInputArgsCount());
                            for (int z = 0; z < transactionActionInfo.getChaincodeInputArgsCount(); ++z) {
                                out("     Transaction action %d has chaincode input argument %d is: %s", j, z,
                                        printableString(new String(transactionActionInfo.getChaincodeInputArgs(z), "UTF-8")));
                            }

                            out("   Transaction action %d proposal response status: %d", j,
                                    transactionActionInfo.getProposalResponseStatus());
                            out("   Transaction action %d proposal response payload: %s", j,
                                    printableString(new String(transactionActionInfo.getProposalResponsePayload())));

                            TxReadWriteSetInfo rwsetInfo = transactionActionInfo.getTxReadWriteSet();
                            if (null != rwsetInfo) {
                                out("   Transaction action %d has %d name space read write sets", j, rwsetInfo.getNsRwsetCount());

                                for (TxReadWriteSetInfo.NsRwsetInfo nsRwsetInfo : rwsetInfo.getNsRwsetInfos()) {
                                    final String namespace = nsRwsetInfo.getNaamespace();
                                    KvRwset.KVRWSet rws = nsRwsetInfo.getRwset();

                                    int rs = -1;
                                    for (KvRwset.KVRead readList : rws.getReadsList()) {
                                        rs++;

                                        out("     Namespace %s read set %d key %s  version [%d:%d]", namespace, rs, readList.getKey(),
                                                readList.getVersion().getBlockNum(), readList.getVersion().getTxNum());

                                        if ("bar".equals(channelId) && blockNumber == 2) {
                                            if ("example_cc_go".equals(namespace)) {
                                                if (rs == 0) {
                                                    assertEquals("a", readList.getKey());
                                                    assertEquals(1, readList.getVersion().getBlockNum());
                                                    assertEquals(0, readList.getVersion().getTxNum());
                                                } else if (rs == 1) {
                                                    assertEquals("b", readList.getKey());
                                                    assertEquals(1, readList.getVersion().getBlockNum());
                                                    assertEquals(0, readList.getVersion().getTxNum());
                                                } else {
                                                    fail(format("unexpected readset %d", rs));
                                                }

                                                TX_EXPECTED.remove("readset1");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    rs = -1;
                                    for (KvRwset.KVWrite writeList : rws.getWritesList()) {
                                        rs++;
                                        String valAsString = printableString(new String(writeList.getValue().toByteArray(), "UTF-8"));

                                        out("     Namespace %s write set %d key %s has value '%s' ", namespace, rs,
                                                writeList.getKey(),
                                                valAsString);

                                        if ("bar".equals(channelId) && blockNumber == 2) {
                                            if (rs == 0) {
                                                assertEquals("a", writeList.getKey());
                                                assertEquals("400", valAsString);
                                            } else if (rs == 1) {
                                                assertEquals("b", writeList.getKey());
                                                assertEquals("400", valAsString);
                                            } else {
                                                fail(format("unexpected writeset %d", rs));
                                            }

                                            TX_EXPECTED.remove("writeset1");
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!TX_EXPECTED.isEmpty()) {
              //  fail(TX_EXPECTED.get(0));
            }
        } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferRuntimeException e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }
    }
```

The utility method printableString()

```
static String printableString(final String string) {
    int maxLogStringLength = 10000;
    if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
        return string;
    }

    String ret = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "\n");

    ret = ret.substring(0, Math.min(ret.length(), maxLogStringLength)) + (ret.length() > maxLogStringLength ? "..." : "");

    return ret;

}
```

Comment: I see that this is Java. do you have the equivalent for Javascript?